# how to fast my mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

hello here is mysql query.

```
SELECT pbi.iBillItemID,
   pbi.vItemCode,
   pbi.vDescription,
   if(
      pb.iLab = 0,
      pbi.iQty,
      (  pbi.iQty
       - ifnull(
            (SELECT sum(p_bi.iQty)
               FROM patientbillitem p_bi, patientbillpayment p_b
              WHERE     p_bi.vRefReceipt = p_b.vReceiptNo
                    AND p_b.iBillNo = p_iBillNo
                    AND p_bi.vItemCode = pbi.vItemCode),
            0)))
   iQty
   FROM patientbillitem pbi,
   patientbillpayment pb,
   patient_service ps,
   patient_service_category psc
   WHERE pbi.iBillNo = pb.iBillNo
   AND pb.iBillNo = p_iBillNo
   AND pbi.vItemCode = ps.iServiceID
   AND ps.iCategoryID = psc.Asc_ID
   AND pbi.iPatID = p_iPatID
```

above mysql query performing to slow actually p_bi.vItemCode = pbi.vItemCode using in this query is varchar field thats why it is taking too much time to execute i try to add full text index on this column then it working very fastly but problem is full text index only support with constant string. can any one give me solution for this query thank you.

Comment: is this mysql or sql-server ? Both are very different

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: How about the index of your table?

Comment: index on p_b.iBillNo

Comment: this is mysql query.

Comment: what do you mean constant string

Comment: mean i just add keyword in string or static string. is fulltext search index work on run time columns?

Comment: You mean you cant make it an index?

Answer (score 1):

1) index on vRefReceipt, iBillNo, vItemCode

2) make the subquery as a temp table or CTE (Common Table Expression) then select from it.

Answer (score 0):

Just:

Make an index to all of our `primary key` which is used by your query then simulate how long it takes than `before` and `after`.